# Passing props to Field validate gives previous props values

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Passing props to Field validate gives previous props values, especially in this case the Quantity. Using [this sandbox](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRvmXq), follow these steps:

1. Open sandbox then console
2. Set Value to 2
3. Select Quantity to 2
4. From console, quantity is still set to 1
5. Press Submit
6. Pop up has correct values `{"amount":4,"quantity":"2","value":"2"}`
7. Change Value to 1 (Now in Console Quantity is 2)
8. Error message appears

Instead, what should happen:

- Step 4 & 7 should have correct Quantity. props has previous value, not updated
- Step 8 should not have error because 1 * 2 = 2
- Field validation should have current props values

I followed [this issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/4017) to handle passing props to validate function, but it seems whenever the props changed the component did not get updated and instead will have the previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is works for me.

Replace this code with your `validateAmount` function.

```
validateAmount = (amount, e) => {
      //const { value, quantity } = this.props.formValues
      console.log('amount:', amount, 'value:', e.value, 'quantity:', e.quantity)
      if (amount < e.value * e.quantity) return 'Nope!'
}
```

Here second parameter gets the current state of form values. First answer was taken the Redux State.

Comment: Looks good! I should have realised the 2nd argument for `validate` gives all values.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
validateAmount = (amount) => {
 //const { value, quantity } = this.props.formValues
 // instead for using values from props ,get values from current state 
  const { value, quantity } = store.getState().form.simple.values;
  console.log('amount:', amount, 'value:', value, 'quantity:', quantity)
  if (amount < value * quantity) return 'Nope!'
}
```

Comment: How does that make a difference? formValues is already from redux's state.